# Files too large warning in Github Desktop after configuring Git LFS

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm having issues with github desktop, spewing the 'Files too large' warning when trying to commit, even though I ran the Git LFS configuration already.
In total, there are 11 files causing this issue and they're all in the same folder.

I installed Git LFS and added the problematic folder to the git lfs track with git bash, as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/configuring-git-large-file-storage), but instead of associating a file type, I associated the problematic folder directory.

After having done this, and verifying that the .gitattributes file is indeed changed, I tried to commit my pending changelist with github desktop again.

**The problem:**
I'm still getting the warning from GitHub Desktop, saying that Files are too large, with a suggestion that I should use Git LFS instead.

How do I solve this?

Edit 1: Added picture: [image: Warning]
Edit 2: push -> commit

Comment: could you post the exact error message?

Comment: I added the picture with an edit.

Comment: Just add the folder to your `.gitignore`?

Comment: "I tried to push my pending" so it seems they are already committed. Commit is not pushing. Just to make sure we are on common ground here, could you run a git status and post the result?

Comment: @DaemonPainter My bad, I ment ' I tried to commit my pending'. Editted in OP.

Comment: Is this a Template repository?

Comment: This is not a template repository, no.

Comment: my answer assumes you already followed [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/moving-a-file-in-your-repository-to-git-large-file-storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but instead of associating a file type, I associated the problematic folder directory

I suggest you don't do that, as it is clearly stated:

> To associate a file type in your repository with Git LFS, enter git
> lfs track followed by the name of the file extension you want to
> automatically upload to Git LFS. [source](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/configuring-git-large-file-storage)

run instead `git lfs track '<problematic folder>/*.dll'`. Indeed, `.gitattributes` do not, by default, track nested folders recursively - as suggested in [issue #3963](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3963).

> The rules by which the pattern matches paths are the same as in
> .gitignore files (see [gitignore[5]](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)), with a few exceptions:
>
> - negative patterns are forbidden
> - *patterns that match a directory do not recursively match paths inside that directory* (so using the trailing-slash path/ syntax is
>   pointless in an attributes file; use path/** instead) [source](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#:%7E:text=A%20gitattributes%20file%20is%20a%20simple%20text%20file,followed%20by%20an%20attributes%20list%2C%20separated%20by%20whitespaces.)

See also [issue #2214](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2214)

Comment: I retried to run the git lfs track {large file directory here} again, and I can confirm that it works with a directory to a single file. Any idea how to specify certain file types to track, but only inside a certain directory: example: track only .dll files inside of a certain file directory, but no other .dll files?

Comment: For example, *.dll should match all dlls in your root, folder\*.dll should match all dll inside "folder" but nowhere else

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already committed the large files to your normal git repo locally. You need to edit your commits with `git rebase` or `git filter-branch`.

Comment: I did not commit the large files, since every time I was prompted with the 'Files too large' warning, I cancelled the commit.

Comment: @Thrindil What command gives the "files to large" warning?

Comment: Pressing the 'Commit to main' button in github desktop.

Comment: @Thrindil I'm not familiar with Github Desktop's UI. I suggest checking two things: 1. Be sure the large files are not added to the git index. From the command line, you can do `git status` to check. You will have to do some googling to find the equivalent action in Github Desktop. 2. Add the folder containing these large files to your `.gitignore` file. I am assuming that doing so doesn't interfere with Git LFS.

Comment: "Commit to main" is equivalent to just commit to "main" (ex master) locale branch, for those who wonder (like I was). No push.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did a 'git status' in git bash, and it says
Untracked files: {directory of files I added to the git lfs track}

Comment: Also, for everyone suggesting to add the directory to my .gitignore file: that would solve my problem, yes. But that's also walking around the issue by just not using Git LFS, and I feel like I'll be stuck with the same question some day in the future if I take the easy route now.

Comment: @Thrindil Thanks for the clarification. I haven't used Git LFS, so I was uncertain how it interacts with `.gitignore`. That's why I explicitly stated my assumption above, which is incorrect from what you say. So please ignore that suggstion.